# moment js create dynamic clocks

Tags: time, momentjs, clock

I created clocks using **moment.js** and **moment-timezone-with-data**
clocks are showing for several locations and only updating on page refresh.
I would like to turn the clocks to dynamic clocks which change every minute (seconds are unnecessary)

here is my full JS code

```
const clocks = [
    "Asia/Tel_Aviv",
    "Europe/Budapest",
    "Asia/Shanghai",
    "Europe/London",
    "America/New_York",
  ];

  let i = 0;
  const titles = ["Tel Aviv", "Valletta", "Shanghai", "London", "Boston"];
  const box = document.querySelector(".box");

  box.append(
    ...clocks.map((timeZone) => {
      const zone = document.createElement("div");
      const time = document.createElement("div");
      const cityTitle = document.createElement("h4");
      zone.classList.add("zone");
      time.classList.add("time", "d-flex", "justify-content-between");

      // Creating box
      zone.append(time, cityTitle);

      time.append(
        ...Array.from(moment().tz(timeZone).format("HH:mm"), (character) => {
          const span = Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), {
            textContent: character,
          });

          if (character === ":") {
            span.classList.add("no-bg");
          }

          return span;
        })
      );
      cityTitle.append(titles[i]);

      i++;
      return zone;
    })
  );
```

and the only HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Full pan here
https://codepen.io/hamergil/pen/LYxQBqM

Would love to get an assistance
Thanks

Comment: Look into [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: OK @Sebastian Simon thanks for your assistance. I ended up using setInterval. built a function which create the clocks every second.. codepan updated